# What does"there was never an us" mean or imply here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does"there was never an us" mean or imply here?

> Relationship Status
>   __ Single
>   __ Taken
>   __ There was never an us

[image: Relationship Status printed on black cloth]

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following question and its choices:

```
What is your favorite vegetable?

(  )  broccoli

(  )  asparagus 

(  )  spinach

(  )  VEGETABLES ARE FOR FARM ANIMALS.
```

The question, as asked, wants a noun as its answer, but one of the answers is a full sentence, *Vegetables are for farm animals*.   That answer is meant to be a humorous analogue of "None of the above" or "This question does not apply to me. It makes an assumption that I have a favorite vegetable when I hate all vegetables."

Your question and its choices work in a similar way, although your question wants an adjective as answer:

```
[What is your] Relationship Status?

 (  ) [I AM ] single

 (  ) [I AM ] taken  (taken = someone has claimed me as their own; I am unavailable)

 (  ) THERE NEVER WAS AN US
```

Just as in the vegetables example, that final choice also means "This question does not apply to me".

The pronoun **us** is being cast into a noun meaning "a couple who are committed to being with each other" and the indefinite article **an** specifies an instance of that class. So, to paraphrase:

> There never was a couple committed to each other.

The answer is meant to apply to the person answering it. The meaning is not perfectly clear in context, but we might understand that answer to mean "I have never been in a committed relationship".

Comment: I can think of two plausible situations where I'd check off the third answer in the OP's image. One would be exactly what you say: "I have never been in a committed relationship". The other would be I had very recently been in a relationship, but the heartache of the recent breakup has me in a state of denial, and so I'd rather check THERE WAS NEVEN AN US than check SINGLE. The poignant lyrics to Ken Yates' [_The One That Got Away_](http://www.songlyrics.com/ken-yates/the-one-that-got-away-lyrics/) come to mind.

Comment: @J.R.  I just assumed the third choice was the bitter/cynical option.  :)

Comment: @J.R. As I say, "the meaning is not perfectly clear, but we might understand...."  With respect to Andrew's suggestion, I would ask, do true cynics or the truly embittered even bother to fill out such questionnaires?  :)

Comment: If it is a cynical option, the sentence should be there never "is" an us, instead of "was", right? It implies the person doesn't believe in relationship